# is_file returning false when using absolute path

Tags: php, file

I am trying to use the is_file() function to check if an image exists.
Here is what I do :

```
<?php if(is_file("/images/tours/crop/$image")){ ?>
    <img src="/images/tours/crop/<?php echo $image ?>"> 
<?php } 
else {echo "Original image has not been cropped yet";} ?>
```

The image exists. When I just output the image, it appears. However, the function always returns false (and I'm getting the error).
I thought it was a Windows problem, but when putting it on our demo server under Linux, the problem is still here.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: That's an absolute **URL** path, which has little-to-no resemblance to your filesystem. you're essentially doing `c:\images\tours\...`, when it should be more like `/path/to/site/document/root/images/etc...` PHP has no knowledge nor could it care less what your website's URL space looks like. PHP cares only about the webserver's filesystem.

Comment: I think your definition of absolute path is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`is_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php) is taking an absolute path as on the machine's filesystem. Unless you have `/images` at the root of your filesystem, it's not going to work.

What you most likely want is something similar to

```
is_file("/var/www/html/application/images/tours/crop/$image")
```

(that would be whatever your application's path is, which can be determined with `__DIR__` or `dirname(__FILE__)`).

Comment: That was my problem, I was going with the URL absolute path instead of the filesystem absolute path

Answer (score 0):

Use the complete path to the file with `__DIR__` or `dirname(__FILE__)`

For example:

`is_file(__DIR__.'/path/to_your_file.jpg');`